# WaitCondition received failed message: 'Configuration failed.'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a CFT stack from CDK java project. From cloudformation service create the CFT template yaml in AWS, Finally I am getting an error: **WaitCondition received failed message: 'Configuration failed.' for uniqueId: i-07f7991f7bf96d427**

Acually all the services and Events CREATE COMPLETE after then finally getting ROLLBACK_COMPLETE (all the Resources and events DELETE COMPLETE)

[CloudFormation stack details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EMFa.png)

Followed by YAML template

```
MasterNodeWaitHandle:<br/>
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle<br/>
    Metadata:<br/>
      aws:cdk:path: CdkStack/MasterNodeWaitHandle<br/>
  MasterNodeWaitCondition:<br/>
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition<br/>
    Properties:<br/>
      Handle:<br/>
        Ref: MasterNodeWaitHandle<br/>
      Timeout: "18000"<br/>
    DependsOn:<br/>
             - renderingserver1<br/>
    Metadata:<br/>
      aws:cdk:path: CdkStack/MasterNodeWaitCondition<br/>
```